# Select n largest values from a table

Tags: sql, mysql

How can I select the 100 largest rows in a table based on a column 'score'?

I can find the largest score in the 'score' column with:

```
SELECT max(score) FROM mTable
```

And then obtain that row(s):

```
SELECT * FROM mTable WHERE score=largestScore
```

But how would I wrap this up and obtain the following 99 lower scored rows?

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM MTABLE t
ORDER BY t.score DESC
LIMIT 100
```

Comment: Thanks. Should really have thought of doing it that way!

Comment: well, i did wonder if it was intentional, but it didn't look like any of the standard forms!

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: I appreciate your honesty.  Not much, but a little =)

Answer (score 2):

Formatted:

```
Select * 
 from mtable 
order by score desc  
limit 100
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT columnList
FROM mTable
ORDER BY score DESC
LIMIT 100
```

Comment: @OMG : I feel dirty when I use '*'! ;)