# MySQL - Find the "Max" Absolute Value of 10 records across multiple columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, max

I have a table that looks something like:

```
 Country | Item | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4
 4       | 4    | .152 | .01  | .65  | 1 
 9       | 6    | .145 | .98  | .469 | .001
 56      | 7    | .001 | .987 | .011 | .223
 78      | 2    | -18  | .269 | -.70 | .1
```

And so on. I want to find the top 10 max ABS(entries) from `Col1`,`Col2`,`Col3`,`Col4`. So in this case, the answer would be:

```
-18
1 
.987
.98
-.70
.65
.469
.223 
....
```

And so on. But how would I do this? I came across both [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384380/select-n-largest-values-from-a-table) which details how to find the max absolute value n columns based on only a  *single* coumn, and also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71022/sql-max-of-multiple-columns/331873#331873) but that only finds the max of the row *per each* row. How can I combine the two?

**EDIT**

As suggested in an answer, I tried something like this:

```
SELECT MAX(ABS(`Col1`)) as `absValue` FROM Table1
UNION ALL 
SELECT MAX(ABS(`Col2`)) as `absValue` FROM Table1 
UNION ALL 
SELECT MAX(ABS(`Col3`)) as `absValue` FROM Table1
UNION ALL 
SELECT MAX(ABS(`Col4`)) as `absValue` FROM Table1
ORDER BY `absValue` DESC
LIMIT 10
```

But got:

```
18
1
0.9869999885559082
0.699999988079071
```

What am I doing wrong? **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/38261d/1)**

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!!

Comment: I'm thinking UNION. Something like SELECT Col1 AS 'a' FROM mytable UNION SELECT Col2 AS 'a' FROM mytable UNION ....... ORDER BY 'a' LIMIT 10;
SQLFiddle keeps dieing on my so haven't got a test

Comment: @DavidK-J Try [**rextester**](http://rextester.com/l/mysql_online_compiler)

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza lol.. It just breaks faster and more verbosely

Comment: @DavidK-J Well first time that happen to me. But I use rextester more for Sql Server and Oracle, and use sqlFiddle to `TEXT to DDL`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 SELECT  `value` 
 FROM (
           SELECT col1 as `value`  FROM yourTable
           UNION all
           SELECT col2 as `value`  FROM yourTable
           UNION all
           SELECT col3 as `value`  FROM yourTable
           UNION all
           SELECT col4 as `value`  FROM yourTable
      ) T
ORDER BY `value` DESC
LIMIT 10
```

As David and Kamil said, you dont need the subquery

**[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cf246/3)**

```
SELECT col1 as `value`  FROM Table1
UNION all
SELECT col2 as `value`  FROM Table1
UNION all
SELECT col3 as `value`  FROM Table1
UNION all
SELECT col4 as `value`  FROM Table1
ORDER BY `value` DESC
LIMIT 10
```

After **QUESTION EDIT** try

```
SELECT ABS(`Col1`) as `absValue` FROM Table1
UNION ALL 
SELECT ABS(`Col2`) as `absValue` FROM Table1 
UNION ALL 
SELECT ABS(`Col3`) as `absValue` FROM Table1
UNION ALL 
SELECT ABS(`Col4`) as `absValue` FROM Table1
ORDER BY `absValue` DESC
LIMIT 10
```

OR to get the exact output

```
SELECT `Col1` as `value` FROM Table1
UNION ALL 
SELECT `Col2` as `value` FROM Table1 
UNION ALL 
SELECT `Col3` as `value` FROM Table1
UNION ALL 
SELECT `Col4` as `value` FROM Table1
ORDER BY ABS(`value`) DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Someone agrees :)

Comment: @DavidK-J Yes, but im not sure if you can just put the`ORDER BY` at the end like you suggest, so I use the subquery syntaxis to be sure.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I'm almost certain that you can :-)

Comment: @KamilG. You are right. I update to Include that solution.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Thank you for the answer, but just realized my question changed a bit so I have reopened it up :)

Comment: Now I dont understand the problem. Did you update the sample data? How you get 18? and what is the result you want?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Thanks!!! Just realized what a simple mistake it was to call MAX(ABS()) when I was already ordering them at the end :)

Answer (score 1):

For every column get their 10 greatest values and retrieve 10 top values from all of them:

```
select max_value
from (
  (select col1 AS max_value
  from yourtable
  order by col1 desc
  limit 10)
  union all
  (select col2
  from yourtable
  order by col2 desc
  limit 10)
  union all
  (select col3
  from yourtable
  order by col3 desc
  limit 10)
  union all
  (select col4
  from yourtable
  order by col4 desc
  limit 10)
  ) foo
order by max_value desc
limit 10
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from ( 
select Col1 as data from database1 
UNION 
select Col2 as data from database1 
UNION 
select Col3 as data from database1 
UNION 
select Col4 as data from database1 
) as T order by data desc ;
```

The union command is really helpful in this scenerio

Comment: so how is your answer different from mine?  Also you need `UNION ALL` other wise you will remove duplicated values.